# String preceeded by @ gets an error: unexpected '@' in program

Tags: objective-c, ios6

Can anybody tell me what's wrong with this statement? (it's complaining about the @ before the "Services" string). It's the same as multiple examples I have found... I tried a "Clean" but still no luck.

```
NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @”Services” ofType: @”plist”];
```

Comment: Have you copy-pasted this code direct from your IDE?

Comment: Take a look at your quotes. `"` is not the same as `”`. Be sure you're using the first (and not the second).

Comment: Hi Matt... thank you... missed that one completely!  Please turn your comment into an answer so I can reward points...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you've copy-pasted this code direct from your IDE, I would start by looking at why you have abnormal quotes:

`@”Services”` is not the same as `@"Services"`

Answer (score 2):

You need to fix your quotes!

```
NSString *bundle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource: @"Services" ofType: @"plist"];
```